# How escape apostrophe in PHP json_encode

Tags: php, twig

I am passing a json_encode object into a button.

```
 <button aria-controls="web-share-fallback" aria-expanded="false"
    class="c-share__link btn-link underline font-normal"
    data-js="web-share track" data-web-share='{{
    post.getWebShare()|json_encode }}' data-track-key="Web Share" data-track-data='[{"action": "web-share"}]'>
```

Now `getWebShare()` returns an array which seems to be breaking in the following string.
[image]

The word `can't` seems to be causing the string to end which prevent the button from firing up. `json_encode` doesn't seem to be solving this.

```
  public function getWebShare() {
    foreach ($this->web_share as &$value) {
      $value = addslashes($value);
    }
    return $this->web_share;
  }
```

The method [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) does seem to be adding the `\` to the `can't` word trying to scape it but it still breaking the full string as shown in the image above.

How can I go about the string from closing on the single apostrophe?

Comment: to fix this you would need to put the json_encode into that function, then add the slashes. If you look closely at your dom you see it full of syntax errors because the quotes are not escaped (also your singles are rendered are double which doesn't help), or you could make a new filter like `post.getWebShare()|json_encode|addslashes` idk twig but you get the idea

Comment: Have you tried to use double quote for the attribute instead of the single quote. data-web-share="{{post.getWebShare()|json_encode }}"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `json_encode` only encode data into valid JSON format. To use a JSON string (or any string for that matter) as a valid HTML tag attribute, you should use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or equivlant way to treat it.

Twig's [escape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html) filter should work for your case.

```
<button aria-controls="web-share-fallback" aria-expanded="false"
    class="c-share__link btn-link underline font-normal"
    data-js="web-share track" data-web-share='{{
    post.getWebShare()|json_encode|escape }}' data-track-key="Web Share" data-track-data='[{"action": "web-share"}]'>
```